# Symfony form: create multiple emails fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Update**
I found in the Symfony docs the answer and an example tutorial to my case: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage

---

How can I assign multiple email fields to a form in Symfony 3.1?
In my entity I have:

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(name="notification_emails", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $notificationEmails;

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getNotificationEmails()
{
    return $this->notificationEmails;
}

/**
 * @param array $notificationEmails
 */
public function setNotificationEmails($notificationEmails)
{
    $this->notificationEmails = $notificationEmails;
}
```

In my form I have:

```
   $builder->add(
       'notificationEmails',
        CollectionType::class,
        array(
           'entry_type' => EmailType::class,
            'label' => 'Add more emails separated by comma',
            'attr' => array(
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
            ),
        )
    );
```

But this doesn't work :(

Comment: Please, specify what you mean with "_But this doesn't work_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Collection` type field, only if you are providing multiple email fields for each one email; with some help of `javascript` and having `Add new email` button.

If users are going to add **emails separated by comma**, you don't need a `Collection` Type field. Keep it simple Text type field with help text as you have done.

Now, in `setter` [`setNotificationEmails`], you should split the csv email string to array and feed to ORM. ORM does the rest in order to save in the database.

You should do the  vice-versa in getter [`getNotificationEmails`] (converting array to string). So your form can represent comma separated emails.

In case above doesn't work, as I doubt, the form might not read data from getter. In that case, you can always use a [Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). It's so useful.

Comment: I actually found on the docs an example about this case: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage